# RichFaces checkbox tree

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I'm implementing RichFaces checkbox tree, and I've got a problem... I need to mark all the child nodes as selected when user selects root node...

I guees it should be done using some javascript function called when users selects root node...

any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time with javascript, I decided to move to server side. 
So, to implement the above feature tree nodes are sending ajax requests on each click, then server-side performs selection or deselection of all the child nodes, and after request processing is finished tree component gets rerendered. The following code demonstrates single node content:

```
<rich:tree id="tree" ...
<rich:treeNode ...
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{_node.selected}">
           <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{_node.select(_node.selected)}" reRender="tree">
           </a4j:support>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>
```

Where **_node.select(_node.selected)** does all the job on server side.