# Checkbox indeterminate state for richfaces tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have richfaces4 tree with check box for each node,Now I need to handle checkbox state to

- selected (check sign),
- unselected (empty),
- partially selected (full square).

These state I need to handle though jquery or javascript code. jquery/javascript method should trigger whenever any checkbox clicked on leaf node and change parent node checkbox state.
Below jquery code I tried but its works only for one scenario that is  when parent node is checked all child nodes are in checked state.

```html
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
      var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
      container = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
      container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
      indeterminate: false,
      checked: checked
 });
```

**JSF Code**

```html
<rich:tree id="tree" nodeType="#{node.type}" var="node"
           value="#{treeBean.rootNodes}" toggleType="client"
           selectionType="ajax" toggleNodeEvent="click"
           selectionChangeListener="#{treeBean.selectionChanged}">
  <rich:treeNode type="country" id="country" onclick="" handleClass="even odd">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="small" value="true" />
    #{node.name}
  </rich:treeNode>
  <rich:treeNode type="company" id="company" handleClass="even odd">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="small" value="true" />
    #{node.name}
  </rich:treeNode>
  <rich:treeNode type="cd" id="cd">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="small" handleClass="even odd"/>
    #{node.artist} - #{node.name} - #{node.year}
  </rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>
```

To handle indeterminate state I am adding jquery to add span tag after input checkbox tag using below code snippet

```html
$.fn.checkbox = function () {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
   if(!$(this).next().hasClass('mycheckBox')){
    $(this).after("<span class=mycheckBox></span>")
   }                                                       
  });
 }
```

Through CSS I am handling styles for all three states of checkbox.

Comment: with writing some js code.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `.rf-trn-ico-cst`, following [the class documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/appe-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters.html#__literal_rich_treenode_literal) and [customizing](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming-Customizing_skins).

That said, your question is very hard to understand, let's clarify some points:

A tree node is either (depending on the styling):

- selected (check sign),
- unselected (empty),
- partially selected (full square).

Is the latter the one you call `indeterminate`?

Example (that picture is not an actual richface tree):

[image: tree checkboxes example]

### After topic edit

There is already a self-answered topic about that, but I strongly discourage you to do the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/6237015/2375207 (a ajax query foreach click just for the state)

Other topic to read, not solved but gives clues to the success:

- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/160446?tstart=0
- [richface tree with selectitem (checkbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585285/richface-tree-with-selectitem-checkbox)
- [Check All box for Richfaces Treenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461349/check-all-box-for-richfaces-treenode) (adapt that code for partial children selection)

I fear that the jsf checkbox is a boolean (can only active or not, impossible to get a partial state), can you show us your jsf code?

Is it possible to use another library to render a checkboxed tree like https://www.jstree.com/ ?

Comment: Yes I need to achieve this Implementation, whenever any node checkbox is clicked then parent node check box should change there state. How i can do with javascript or jquery to handle this checkbox states